# MPMoviePlayerController thumbnail images issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

We have a http live streaming running on our iOS app. We want to get thumbnail images every 1 minute. I tried using MPMoviePlayerController methods

```
thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:
```

and

```
requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption:
```

But both these options return nil. The documentation doesn't say if these methods do not work for http live streaming. Any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Now documentation for this method says:
"This method is not not called when the source URL is an HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) content source. See HTTP Live Streaming Overview."

Answer (score 0):

Try registering for MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification before calling this method and on getting notification check value of this key MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey. In case image capture was successful value of this key will contain a valid UIImage for you to use.